# How to get dynamically created textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

hi friends Actually i have 2 questions..
I am creating a social website like facebook...
In this website i have multiple posts which are coming from database
If anyone want to give comment on this post then only first post is working..but the comment of first post is going to the last post..

```
<%String sql="select * from post ORDER BY id DESC";
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);%>
<input type="text" id="postboxwritereview" name="postboxwritereview" placeholder="write a review" onkeypress="loadXMLDoc2()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("postboxwritereview").onkeypress = function(event){
            if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){
               var xmlhttp;
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("postbox_bottom_my_review").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
var x = document.getElementById("postboxwritereview").value;
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'insertReview.jsp?user='+x+'&p_id=<%=post_id%>&p_uid=<%=post_uid%>&author_uid=<%=u_id%>', true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("postboxwritereview").value="";
}
};
</script>
```

And second problem is that..
I am getting ajax response from servlet and showing that resppnse into a div 
But there are many divs created dynamically with same id..so ajax response from first post is going to the last post..Plz help me
Here is the code..
AJAX CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{ xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("showRating").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
var username=$('input:radio[name=rating_blog]:checked').val();
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'InsertRating?user='+username+'&p_id=<%=post_id%>&p_uid=<%=post_uid%>', true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="submit" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">
<div>
<input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating_blog" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()">
<input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating_blog" value="2" onclick="this.form.submit()">
<input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating_blog" value="3" onclick="this.form.submit()">
</div>
```

Comment: How is this question related with java and JSP ?

Comment: I would start by using jQuery consistently in your code, especially in your AJAX code. For example, the complexity in `loadXMLDoc()` can be replaced by using `$.ajax()`.

Comment: How did this get up voted?

Comment: Please format the code. It makes it easier for us to understand and reply.

Comment: actually i dont have much knowledge about $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique on page!

If You use jQuery why don't use '$.ajax()'?

You can try this:

```
function loadXMLDoc(event){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            $(event.target).find("#showRating").text = xmlhttp.responseText
        }
    }
    var username=$('input:radio[name=rating_blog]:checked').val();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", 'InsertRating?user='+username+'&p_id=<%=post_id%>&p_uid=<%=post_uid%>', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: same problem brother..id is unique but every time showRating div is created when data is coming from database

Comment: Did you coll it like this: onclick="loadXMLDoc(event)"?